# Upload large file to Dropbox through dropbox-v2-api nodejs

Tags: node.js, dropbox-api

I am using **dropbox-v2-api** npm package to upload the large file to Dropbox
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dropbox-v2-api
In the doc to upload the large file they used this piece of code
I am trying to upload the file from the postman.Please guide me how i used the below piece of code to upload the large file to the Dropbox ??

```
const CHUNK_LENGTH = 100;
//create read streams, which generates set of 100 (CHUNK_LENGTH) characters of values: 1 and 2
const firstUploadChunkStream = () => utils.createMockedReadStream('1', CHUNK_LENGTH); 
const secondUploadChunkStream = () => utils.createMockedReadStream('2', CHUNK_LENGTH);

sessionStart((sessionId) => {
    sessionAppend(sessionId, () => {
        sessionFinish(sessionId);
    });
});

function sessionStart(cb) {
    dropbox({
        resource: 'files/upload_session/start',
        parameters: {
            close: false
        },
        readStream: firstUploadChunkStream()
    }, (err, result, response) => {
        if (err) { return console.log('sessionStart error: ', err) }
        console.log('sessionStart result:', result);
        cb(result.session_id);
    });
}


function sessionAppend(sessionId, cb) {
    dropbox({
        resource: 'files/upload_session/append',
        parameters: {
            cursor: {
                session_id: sessionId,
                offset: CHUNK_LENGTH
            },
            close: false,
        },
        readStream: secondUploadChunkStream()
    }, (err, result, response) => {
        if(err){ return console.log('sessionAppend error: ', err) }
        console.log('sessionAppend result:', result);
        cb();
    });
}

function sessionFinish(sessionId) {
    dropbox({
        resource: 'files/upload_session/finish',
        parameters: {
            cursor: {
                session_id: sessionId,
                offset: CHUNK_LENGTH * 2
            },
            commit: {
                path: "/result.txt",
                mode: "add",
                autorename: true,
                mute: false
            }
        }
    }, (err, result, response) => {
        if (err) { return console.log('sessionFinish error: ', err) }
        console.log('sessionFinish result:', result);
    });
}
```

In the above coude what does mean **utils** ??
I have file object i used this piece of code

```
const firstUploadChunkStream = () => file.createMockedReadStream('1', CHUNK_LENGTH);
```

I received this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: file.createMockedReadStream is not a function
```